# NFS configuration redhat6.3 64bit

Tags: mount, nfs

I'm getting this error on the client:

```
[root@localhost /]# mount -t nfs 192.168.18.144:/linuxcast-nfs /mnt/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 192.168.18.144:/linuxcast-nfs,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

I don't understand the error. Does the client need additional configuration?

Comment: Did you do `dmesg|tail` as the error message suggested? If so, what did it say? Also, which NFS version is used - could it simply be that you need to use nfs4?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
rpcinfo -p 192.168.18.144
```

to see if there are any NFS/RPC services actually running on the server..

cheers

sc.